# How come there isn't a scene showing the four other kids exiting the factory?

Tags: analysis, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

I've always wondered why there isn't a scene of the other four bad kids exiting the factory towards the end of *Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory*. I know Wonka says "When they leave here they'll be completely restored to their normal terrible old selves". But why did the Crew not show a scene of the kids exiting? What happened to them?

Comment: Would Willie Wonka **lie?**

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a question appropriate if someone doesn't get Wonka's character and the darker implications of the movie, no? *Disclaimer: haven't actually seen the movie*

Comment: I haven't voted down, but I can see why someone would. Why didn't the film makers add a scene to the film? To quote Wonka. There is simply no way of knowing. Why doesn't film X contain imaginary scene Y? Because that's not how it was written!